# Laravel Eloquent Accessing Original

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I trying to get a value from an object I get from one of my model. It only returns me the attributes which is not what I want because it does not correspond to what is in my table. 
**I want to access the original array.**

I did:

```
$entries = Model::where('A', $A)->where('B', $B)->get();

@Foreach ($entries as $entry) 

$entry->id
$entry->name

@Endforeach
```

I tried to add `->original` but it either doesn't work.

Here's partially the first entry of my `var_dump($entries)`

```
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Models\TableA Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => Table A
                    [primaryKey] => id
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => 2

                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => 1

                        )
```

Comment: Can you give an example on what you are actually trying to get?  I'm a little confused.  If you are trying to to convert the model to an array, you can use the `toArray()` method. http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#1725-1735

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When retrieving the original value of an Eloquent model attribute, you
>   can use `getOriginal($key)`

Reference:

- [Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal)
- [Laravel 5.0](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal)

Comment: Up-voted, however link no longer works. Here's a new one for `4.2` http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal and one for `5.0` http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 4.2 and on

```
$entries->toArray()
```

Will provide model attributes only.